# carousel slider displays single item in Angular4

Tags: html, angular

Working in an Angular4 project in this ,I have used  carousel for displaying products,Products are binding from API response .

In my carousel I display the products like single row 3 column format ,If API returns 10 products the 10 th product is get displayed single slide .

I want to merge the 10th product with 1st and 2nd product then display like a 3 column slide .

Html

```
<div class="col-sm-9">
                <section class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-1">
                            <i class="fa fa-user" style="font-size:25px"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <h5>Popular Products</h5>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </section>
                <hr>
                <section class="carousel slide" id="myCarousel">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-12 text-right mb-4">
                                <a class="btn btn-outline-secondary carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev" title="go back">
                                    <i class="fa fa-lg fa-chevron-left"></i>
                                </a>
                                <a class="btn btn-outline-secondary carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next" title="more">
                                    <i class="fa fa-lg fa-chevron-right"></i>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="container p-t-0 m-t-2 carousel-inner">
                        <div class="row row-equal carousel-item {{ i == 0 ? 'active' : '' }} m-t-0" *ngFor="let chunkProducts of productData;let i =index;">
                            <div class="col-sm-4" *ngFor="let slider of chunkProducts;">
                                <div class="card">
                                    <div class="card-img-top card-img-top-250 one">
                                        <img class="img-fluid" [src]="slider['PRODUCT_IMAGE']" alt="Carousel 1">
                                        <img routerLink="/my-cart" class="img-fluid two" [src]="slider['PRODUCT_IMAGE_ONHOVER']" alt="Carousel 1">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="card-block pt-2">
                                        <div class="col-sm-12 text-center card-text">
                                            <span>{{slider.PRODUCT_NAME}}</span>
                                            <br>
                                            <input type="hidden" value="{{slider.PRODUCT_ID}}" #Pname1>
                                            <br>
                                            <span>{{slider.PRODUCT_PRICE}}</span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </section>
```

This is my html file to show the slide as 3 column format.

Component

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.CartdataService.get_New_Products().subscribe(
      data => {
          this.productData = this.chunks(data,3);
          console.log(this.productData);
      });

chunks(array, size) {
    let results = [];
    results = [];
    while (array.length) {
      results.push(array.splice(0, size));
    }
    return results;
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just Change :

```
this.CartdataService.get_New_Products().subscribe(data => {
    this.productData = this.chunks(data.json(),3);

    let last = this.productData[this.productData.length-1].length;
    if(this.productData.length > 1 && last < 3) {
        this.productData[this.productData.length-1] = [ ...this.productData[this.productData.length-1] , ...this.productData[0].slice(0, 3-last) ];
    }

});
```

**[WORKING DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bootstrap-carousel-dynamic2)**

Comment: Specifically ,Why you kept three dots 

this.productData[this.productData.length-1] = [ ...this.productData[this.productData.length-1] , ...this.productData[0].slice(0, 3-last) ]; in this line

Comment: That's es6 spread operator , I have used to combine the array

Comment: Okay ,Thanks for your time .

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49938614/bootstrap-slider-shows-the-active-item-two-times-in-angular4  can you please help me in this issue

Comment: Hi ,I have tried this in my project and it's working fine but I am facing a problem when I minimize the screen it showing the 3 products one by one but I need to show it in single products .I mean in the web view it should be as 3 products slide and in mobile view it should be as a single product slide .Is it possible to do ...could I please help me to get this @VivekDoshi

Comment: @Zhu, that should be provided by plugin , if that doesn't provide that then I can't help you

Comment: I think you misunderstand my words ,please open your solution of this post and in stackblitz view the output in the "Open in new window" option ,now you can see the slider in web view (full screen),now just minimize the screen to the minimum screen size you can see the products to be displayed one below one .I want to change it to be like single slide for Ex : if 10 products in slide in should be shown as 10 single slides not in (3 + 3) slides . Hope you understand my need . Help me if you know how to do this @VivekDoshi

Comment: @Zhu , sorry I dont know